# Set background position according to contents of span with jQuery

Tags: jquery, background-image, background-position

I would like to change the position of a background image to match the numeric contents of a span element.

My html:

```
<div id="ecoBar">
    <div id="ecoSlider"></div>
    <h4>ECO <span id="ecoPercentage">50%</span></h4>
</div>
```

So I have a div#ecoSlider that represents a sliding scale that is 400px wide and a span#ecoPercentage that gives a numeric value. I would like to get that value from the span and apply to my background position.

My jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $('#ecoPercentage').text();
    $('#ecoSlider').css('backgroundPosition', 'value 0');
});
```

I cannot seem to get this working, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing "value" as a string value. Try this instead:

$('#ecoSlider').css('backgroundPosition', value + ' 0');

Comment: thanks that works fine but does not give me the effect I want. How would I take that value strip out the % and times it by 4?

Comment: @mtwallet: `value = parseInt($('#ecoPercentage').text()) * 4;`

Comment: @Orbling thanks for the comment however I get the following error when trying what you suggest 'XML descendants internal method called on incompatible Object'??

Comment: @Orbling my bad I had written this console..log(value)